# Cast to TV from Win 10 won't show programs

Tags: miracast

We have a Windows 10 PC and are trying to cast to our Roku stick on a Samsung TV.  It used to work.  Now all we can see when I connect to the Roku stick from the PC is the desktop and icons on the task bar. The browser window and any other windows don't show up on the TV.

So we can connect from the PC to the Roku successfully but then we can't see the window that is open on the PC so we can't send a movie to the TV.

Maybe a Windows update messed it up?  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Super User :-)
If you have more questions: feel free to ask. If the answer below helped you: select it as accepted and/or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows probably treats the TV as a second screen in "Extend" mode. This means that your browser is either on the TV or on your PC, not on both.

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and switch to "Duplicate" mode in the black PROJECT side bar.

Sometimes no black side bar appears. In this case, wait 4 seconds and press it again. There are 4 modes in total, so you can attempt this up 3 times.